# how to load java script onclick?

Tags: javascript, onclick, load

```
<script src="recentimg.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="JavaScript">
imgr = new Array();
imgr[0] = "noimage.jpeg";
RandomImg = true;
</script>
```

how when i click button .. i make it load random image .. i mean load this script onclick

```
<script language="JavaScript">
imgr = new Array();
imgr[0] = "noimage.jpeg";
RandomImg = false;
</script>
```

i tried

```
<input type="button" onclick="write()" value="load">
<script language="JavaScript">
function write(){RandomImg = false;}
</script>
```

But it not work ..

Note : my web don't support php,ajax load

---

update 
------------ the full code ..

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<script language="JavaScript">
imgr = new Array();
imgr[0] = "https://dl.dropbox.com/u/36050019/Bukraa.coM/noimagejpeg.jpeg";
showRandomImg = true;
boxwidth = 298;
cellspacing = 8;
borderColor = "#F5F5F5";
bgTD = "#000000";
thumbwidth = 80;
thumbheight = 64;
fntsize = 16;
acolor = "#666";
label = "اخبار مصر";
aBold = true;
icon = " ";
text = "comments";
showPostDate = false;
summaryPost = 0;
summaryFontsize = 10;
summaryColor = "#666";
icon2 = " ";
numposts = 4;
home_page = "http://bukraa.blogspot.com/";
</script>
<style>table td {
padding: 0px;
text-align: right;
}</style>
<script src="https://dl.dropbox.com/u/36050019/Bukraa.coM/recentpost.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

..... i want to change label on click to

```
label = "توب نمبر";
```

then when i click button .. my code show new label feeds without refresh page 
can i do it using java script , jquery ?

Comment: Start here: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/08/17/javascript-events-responding-user/

Comment: Can you post the complete HTML file? The last code you posted actually works, but do "nothing" (just set RandomImg to false)..

Answer (score 1):

Little unclear what you're trying to achieve, friend. However, if you want your function to execute when a certain object is clicked, simply add

```
$("#clickme").click(function() {
  //script
});
```

around your script.

For example:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$("#clickme").click(function() {
imgr = new Array();
imgr[0] = "noimage.jpeg";
RandomImg = false;
});
</script>

<div id="clickme">
Click Me!
</div>
```

Here's an example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CWBZz/3/

Comment: Did you take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/CWBZz/3/ ? I would like to think it explains how jquery uses classes and IDs.

Comment: I see you've posted your full script. Could you post your html as well?

Comment: there's no html code .. if you put this full code in html test page you'll see it show feeds content
http://jsfiddle.net/AwPEh/

Comment: I do apologise..I'll look at it tomorrow!